# How to convert a file into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file that has the following text

```
1. Beatles - Revolver (1966)
2. Nirvana - Nevermind (1991)
3. Beatles - Sgt Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band (1967)
4. U2 - The Joshua Tree (1987)
5. Beatles - The Beatles (The White Album) (1968)
6. Beatles - Abbey Road (1969)
7. Guns N' Roses - Appetite For Destruction (1987)
8. Radiohead - Ok Computer (1997)
9. Led Zeppelin - Led Zeppelin 4 (1971)
10. U2 - Achtung Baby (1991)
11. Pink Floyd - Dark Side Of The Moon (1973)
12. Michael Jackson -Thriller (1982)
13. Rolling Stones - Exile On Main Street (1972)
14. Clash - London Calling (1979)
15. U2 - All That You Can't Leave Behind (2000)
16. Weezer - Pinkerton (1996)
17. Radiohead - The Bends (1995)
18. Smashing Pumpkins - Mellon Collie And The Infinite Sadness (1995)
19. Pearl Jam - Ten (1991)
20. Beach Boys - Pet Sounds (1966)
21. Weezer - Weezer (1994)
22. Nirvana - In Utero (1993)
23. Beatles - Rubber Soul (1965)
24. Eminem -The Eminem Show (2002)
25. R.E.M. - Automatic For The People (1992)
26. Radiohead - Kid A (2000)
27. Tool - Aenima (1996)
28. Smashing Pumpkins - Siamese Dream (1993)
29. Madonna - Ray Of Light (1998)
30. Rolling Stones - Sticky Fingers (1971)
...till line 99.
```

so i have to store  the  information  into  a  dictionary  whose  keys  are  the  Band name,  and  the  associated  value  is  a  list  that  contains all  the  best  albums  of  that  Band. Each  entry  of  this  list  is  a  tuple  consisting  of  two  fields: the  Album  name  and  the  Year  in  which  it  was released. I have to get rid of the punctuations and the parenthesis also. Can someone help, please?

Comment: When you have a problem, just use RegEx.  Then you'll have two problems.

Comment: Yes you are basically just dumping this huge question on here, please tell us which part you are having trouble with and you are likely to get help. On an unrelated note the number 1 album was really good :)

Comment: The part of converting this text file into a sorted dictionary, is what I am having trouble with. It should look like: myDict = 
{..., 
'Beach Boys': [('Pet Sounds', '1966')], 
'Bob Marley': [('Legend', '1984')], 
'Beatles': [('Revolver', '1966'), ("
Sgt Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club     
                          Band", '1967'), ('The Beatles (The White Album)', '1968'), ('Abbey Road', '1969'), ('Rubber Soul', '1965')], 'Clash': [('London Calling', '1979')], '
Strokes': [('Is This It', '2001')],...}

Answer (score 2):

Try this for starters. This is no way perfect and you need to take it from here and tweak it for your needs.

```
import re

my_dict = {}
for record in songs:
    year = re.findall('\(([0-9]{4})\)', record)
    band = re.findall('[0-9]+\. (.*)', l.split('-')[0])
    song = re.findall('(.*) \(', record.split('-')[1].strip())

    if song and band and year:
        if my_dict.has_key(band): #alread present, append 
            my_dict[band].append((song, year))
        else: #create new entry
            my_dict[band] = [(song, year)]

print my_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

what I would do is read each line from a file, parse it into a string, split the string at every `.`, then make the first string a key and the second the value. E.X:

```
albumDict = {}
file = open(/path/to/file, "r")
for line in file.readlines():
    splitLine = line.split(".")
    albumDict[splitLine[0]] = splitline[1]
```

EDIT:
Note: This won't check for duplicate entries, and should no way be implemented in a professional setting. If you want to make this usable by multiple people, add a check to make sure that the key doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that might work better for you:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

band_dict = defaultdict(list)
pattern   = re.compile(r"\d+\. (?P<band>.+?) -\s?(?P<album>.+?) \((?P<year>\d+)\)")
with open("musiclist") as f:
    for line in f:
        match = pattern.match(line)
        if match:
            groupdict = match.groupdict()
            band_dict[groupdict['band']].append((groupdict['album'], groupdict['year']))
        else:
            print "Error, no match for line %s" % line

for band in band_dict:
    print band
    for album, year in band_dict[band]:
        print "\t%s: %s" % (album, year)
```

Running this with the data you provided as `musiclist` gives

```
Pink Floyd
    Dark Side Of The Moon: 1973
Beatles
    Revolver: 1966
    Sgt Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band: 1967
    The Beatles (The White Album): 1968
    Abbey Road: 1969
    Rubber Soul: 1965
Clash
    London Calling: 1979
Rolling Stones
    Exile On Main Street: 1972
    Sticky Fingers: 1971
Led Zeppelin
    Led Zeppelin 4: 1971
R.E.M.
    Automatic For The People: 1992
Guns N' Roses
    Appetite For Destruction: 1987
U2
    The Joshua Tree: 1987
    Achtung Baby: 1991
    All That You Can't Leave Behind: 2000
Nirvana
    Nevermind: 1991
    In Utero: 1993
Pearl Jam
    Ten: 1991
Tool
    Aenima: 1996
Beach Boys
    Pet Sounds: 1966
Madonna
    Ray Of Light: 1998
Radiohead
    Ok Computer: 1997
    The Bends: 1995
    Kid A: 2000
Eminem
    The Eminem Show: 2002
Weezer
    Pinkerton: 1996
    Weezer: 1994
Smashing Pumpkins
    Mellon Collie And The Infinite Sadness: 1995
    Siamese Dream: 1993
Michael Jackson
    Thriller: 1982
```

Comment: It is only printing one line. How should I make it print all like in your example? Thank you

Comment: @AbdulKhan do you have the full file in the same directory as the python script?  The code needs a file called "musiclist" with the bands that you want to analyze.  If you've done that then I'll need more information to figure out what's wrong on your end.